# Exception is Occured when Executing a JoinTransaction in EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, seam, entitymanager

I am getting exception is  javax.transaction.NotSupportedException

I am  using jta transaction with jpa when i joined UserTransaction to entityManager i will got this exception

SampleCode:

```
        @Begin(join=true)
        public String tempCustomerMigration(List<DoTempCustomers>  list) {
            try {
             UserTransaction userTx = (UserTransaction) org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance("org.jboss.seam.transaction.transaction");
             userTx.setTransactionTimeout(10 * 60);
             userTx.begin();
             for(DoTempCustomers tempCustomers:list){

                TempCustomers temp=new TempCustomers();
                BeanUtils.copyProperties(temp, tempCustomers);
                entityManager.joinTransaction();
                getEntityManager().persist(temp);
                getEntityManager().flush();
                userTx.commit();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            return "save";

                }
```

log:

```
2012-12-17 16:08:24,834 ERROR [STDERR] javax.transaction.NotSupportedException
2012-12-17 16:08:24,836 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.begin(BaseTransaction.java:79)
2012-12-17 16:08:24,836 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.begin(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:77)
2012-12-17 16:08:24,836 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction.begin(ServerVMClientUserTransaction.java:124)
2012-12-17 16:08:24,836 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.seam.transaction.UTTransaction.begin(UTTransaction.java:39)
2012-12-17 16:08:24,836 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.manam.mobee.migrationCustomerManagement.MigrationCustomerHome.tempCustomerMigration(MigrationCustomerHome.java:253)
2012-12-17 16:08:24,836 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.manam.mobee.migrationCustomerManagement.MigrationCustomerHome.migrateCustomers(MigrationCustomerHome.java:234)
2012-12-17 16:08:24,836 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.manam.mobee.migrationCustomerManagement.MigrationCustomerHome.migrateData(MigrationCustomerHome.java:153)
2012-12-17 16:08:24,836 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2012-12-17 16:08:24,836 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2012-12-17 16:08:24,836 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2012-12-17 16:08:24,836 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
2012-12-17 16:08:24,836 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
2012-12-17 16:08:24,836 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
2012-12-17 16:08:24,836 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
2012-12-17 16:08:24,837 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of exception indicates that the request cannot be executed because the operation is not a supported feature.
For example, because nested transactions are not supported, the Transaction Manager throws this exception when a calling thread that is already associated with a transaction attempts to start a new transaction.
A nested transaction occurs when a thread is already associated with one transaction and attempts to start a second transaction.

Comment: how can i achive this type of excecution.